# how to compare based on Date with DATETIME field of MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a DATETIME field.. I want to search based on Date only.
using below query:

```
select subTitle,count(alertid) as cnt,alertdate from alertmaster a,subscriptionmaster s where s.subId=a.subId GROUP BY a.subId,alertDate
```

I get results grouped by date & time.. e.g.

*xxx 4 2011-04-09 01:03:15*  & *xxx 1 2011-04-09 01:02:11* are shown as different results, which i dnt want. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select date(alertdate) instead.

```
select subTitle,count(alertid) as cnt,date(alertdate) from alertmaster a,subscriptionmaster s where s.subId=a.subId GROUP BY a.subId,date(alertdate)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
... GROUP BY a.subId, DATE(alertDate)
```

the `DATE()` function will extract just the date portion of a date/time field. More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).